# how to extract HTML values when ID values are stored in an array

Tags: javascript

```
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var Temp_Name = result[i];
                var Temp_Val = result[i].val();
                console.log("temp name is ", Temp_Name);

               console.log("temp val is ",Temp_Val);
            }
```

How to get Temp_Val ? Current method is not working.

HTML Code:

```
<input type = "Text" id={{this.Temp_Name}}>
```

I want to store the values of result in DB.

result is [Brand,Size,Product]
Values have to be entered by user in HTML

Comment: What is "not working"? What does this have to do with HTML?

Comment: What is the HTML in your template?

Comment: What is supposed to be in `result` and have you checked it's contents?

Comment: Do you use any fframework? If so, which one? If not, the field value is in `.value`.

Comment: I am not getting Template Value in Temp_Val

Comment: result is an array with parameters like Brand,Price,Product_Name

Comment: There is no `.val()` in javascript. There is the `.value` property for form elements. Are you getting confused with jQuery's `.val()`?

Comment: Ya maybe, let me try

Answer (score 2):

Below should work in DHTML

```
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var Temp_Name = result[i];
            var Temp_Val = document.getElementById(Temp_Name).value;
            console.log("temp name is ", Temp_Name);

           console.log("temp val is ",Temp_Val);
        }
```

Please let me know if you have any questions